# Add documents to elasticsearch if it does not exists

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

I transferred some data from a log generated every day to elasticsearch using logstash, and my logstash output section looks like :

[image]

i keep the same id (id_ot) in both my log file and elasticsearch, but what i would like to do is : if the new coming id ( id_ot) already exists in elasticseach, so i will not insert it. How can i do that in logstash ?

Any help would be really appriciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add the [`action => create` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-action) and if a document already exists with that ID, it is not indexed

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    action => "create"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Val. that's all what i need. Regards

Comment: Val, if i may ask you another question: I implemented ILM for managing  the data which looks like:

Comment: Mohamed, let's close this question and create a new one, so we don't cram too much unrelated topics into this thread, thanks

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking for is an upsert , create the document if dosent exist or update an existing one .
elastic supports this via `doc_as_upsert` option

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert

on the right hand side in the link you can choose the elastic version that matches your version.

Comment: `doc_as_upsert` creates document if its doesnt exist. But if its exists - it will update the document. OP doesnt want to update existing but only create. So Val's answer is the correct. `create` action doesnt update for existing ones.